# Unexpected error on query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When executing this code on SQL Server 2012 through SQL Server Management Studio:

```
PRINT 'Begin';
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
DROP TABLE #TEST; 
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
```

I get the error

> There is already an object named '#TEST' in the database.

and it doesn't even print 'Begin'.

What I am expecting is that the code prints 'Begin' and I have a #TEST table with one column called 'A' and one row containing '1'. Why is my expectation wrong?

Thanks

--- Update ---

By the way, this code returns the same error message:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEST') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEST
GO

PRINT 'Begin';
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
DROP TABLE #TEST; 
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
```

Comment: The error couldn't be clearer than that.  There's already a table `#TEST`.  You must be trying to create the table.  You don't even post the right code.  There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: Did you test it Eric? I'm running 2016 and am getting the same error with this code. There is no object. If I run only the DROP TABLE, it doesn't exist. If I run as-is in the OP, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you try it @Eric ?

Comment: I can't tell you why, but put a "GO" after the "DROP" line, and it works. I would make an answer if I could explain why. I'm sure it's something like an "Application.DoEvents()" call, but since I'm not 100%, I'll just leave it as a comment

Comment: @Aaron I guess because the `GO`command forces ssms to run its statements to the end before starting a new statement. And thus it gives sql server the time to drop the temp table that is normally kept alive until another session is started

Answer (score 2):

Once you run the code once the temp table #TEST already exists.  Once created it lasts until your session is over.  You would need to drop it before you can run it again.

put this at the top and it will work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEST
GO
```

If this doesn't work then the problem then is that you are using the INTO statement twice.  The second call is causing the error because #test would exist after the first into.  It's kind of a bug with error checking SQL I guess.  In order to get around it you either need to use a different temp table name on the second into or put a GO after the DROP table like this

```
PRINT 'Begin';
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
DROP TABLE #TEST; 
GO
SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
```

Alternatively you could just create the table first and then insert into them but then you lose the performance advantages of into - not sure if that is required or not.

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the session and connecting back again? There could be a lock on the table..

Comment: It's because GO signals the end of a batch, so the error checker would restart after the GO.  Read more about GO here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`DROP TABLE #TEST; 
    PRINT 'Begin';
    SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;
    DROP TABLE #TEST; 
    SELECT 1 A INTO #TEST;`